# updating location data in firebase with objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, firebase, mkannotation

Here I am recording the longitude and latitude of the pins dropped on a map. This longitude and latitude is successfully saved in a Firebase database with a unique id every time. The problem is when I try to drag and update location of the pins all the changes are displayed in the latest pin dropped. Please help me out in this. Here is the code I have written so far

```
- (void)addPin:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com/"];

CGPoint tappedPoint = [recognizer locationInView:Mapview];
NSLog(@"Tapped At : %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(tappedPoint));
coordinate= [Mapview convertPoint:tappedPoint toCoordinateFromView:Mapview];
NSLog(@"lat  %f",coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"long %f",coordinate.longitude);
NSNumber *latitudeAnn = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: coordinate.latitude];
NSNumber *longitudeAnn = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: coordinate.longitude];

postRef = [myRootRef childByAutoId];

[postRef setValue:@{@"latitude" : latitudeAnn, @"longitude" : longitudeAnn}];


//[Mapview addAnnotation:]


MKPointAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
myAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate;
[Mapview selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
[self.Mapview addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
recognizer.enabled = NO;
// add an annotation with coord
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)annotationView
didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState
   fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState
{
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = annotationView.annotation.coordinate;
    NSLog(@"Pin dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);

    coordinate = droppedAt;

    NSNumber *updatedLatitudeAnn = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: coordinate.latitude];
    NSNumber *updatedLongitudeAnn = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithDouble: coordinate.longitude];


    [postRef updateChildValues: @{ @"latitude" : updatedLatitudeAnn, @"longitude" : updatedLongitudeAnn}];
}
}
```

Please help me out with this

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, however, your code creates postRef at the top and sets its latitude and longitude and then later in the code you are updating that same postRef? Maybe there's some missing code? when you tap an existing pin, you need to get it's postRef and pass that into the mapView:annotationView method so it knows which ref to update with new coordinates.

Comment: @Jay Actually I am having problem in getting the postref of the pin I tap. I searched everywhere but I don't know how to implement the logic.Sorry I am new with both firebase and mkannotation. Can you help me in this?

Comment: There's lot of options here but one possibility is to create a 'pin object' that stores the MKPointAnnotation, maybe some info about the pin, and a reference to the data stored in Firebase. Then store each 'pin object' in an array. Suppose there are 10 pins, 0-9. Those indexes would refer back to their index (position) in the array. You tap pin 2, you could then retrieve it's pin_object from the array at index 2, get it's postRef and update when the pin is dropped at it's new location. As I said there are a ton of options and this may not be the best but it's a starting point.